# Cannot borrow as mutable

Tags: rust

I would to understand how to insert value in a node in a binary tree:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

// Definition for a binary tree node.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
  pub val: i32,
  pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
  pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

impl TreeNode {
  #[inline]
  pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    TreeNode {
      val,
      left: None,
      right: None
    }
  }
}

/*
            1
          /  \
         2   3
       / 
      4 
*/

fn main() {
    let mut t = TreeNode::new(1);
    t.left = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new (TreeNode::new(2))));
    t.right = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(3))));
    t.left.unwrap().get_mut().left = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(4)))); // throws error
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f6dee87feb4760e509f75017f0b2c2e)

The tree should look like the one as in the comment. On compiling it throws the error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow data in an `Rc` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:35:5
   |
35 |     t.left.unwrap().get_mut().left = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(4))));
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>`
```

How can I assign a new TreeNode to the left of value `2`?

**Update:**
I can't change the type of `left` and `right` from `Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>` to anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you `Rc<RefCell<...>>`ing everything? All you're doing is pushing the borrow checker from compile time to runtime. `RefCell` is an expert-friendly tool used to delay ownership analysis. `Rc` allows you to emulate multiple-ownership semantics. Neither of these should appear in a simple acyclic structure like a binary tree.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo, I agree, since the tree is an unsized type I would recommend something like `Box::<Tree>` or a reference.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - I can't change the definition of TreeNode. This is defined as is. Updated the question as well. Thanks!

Comment: In the long term, I recommend finding a better tutorial/teacher then. This is a truly abysmal way to do a binary tree in Rust. I know that doesn't help you answer this *specific* question, but the point still stands.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - appreciate your input. But this is how it is defined in https://leetcode.com/problems/deepest-leaves-sum/ (if you pick Rust lang).

Comment: Alright, good to know. My comment stands, but go take a look at my answer and see if it provides you any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you meant `borrow_mut()` instead of `get_mut()`

```
fn main() {
    let mut t = TreeNode::new(1);
    t.left = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(2))));
    t.right = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(3))));
    t.left.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().left = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(4))));
}
```

Comment: I just updated the question. I can't change the type, so can't use your proposed solution.

Answer (score 4):

With the updated question in mind, the incantation you're looking for is

```
t.left.unwrap().borrow_mut().left = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(4))));
```

[`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.get_mut) is for when you *already* have a mutable reference to the `RefCell`, and you never have a mutable reference to a thing in an `Rc` for safety reasons. [`borrow_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut), on the other hand, is for circumventing the usual rules and getting a mutable reference to an immutable thing regardless. Note that, in either case, the `Rc` is transparent, since the `Deref` trait takes care of it for us.

It's wordy and clunky, and frankly I blame Leetcode for that. I suspect they told someone to go translate everything into Rust, and that person did not know Rust and just threw everything in a `RefCell` because they didn't know better. So please don't take this as a good representation of idiomatic Rust. That sample code is ugly, plain and simple. Rust is a much prettier language than that, I promise.

Comment: *I blame Leetcode for that* — this has also been my experience with Leetcode + Rust.